# excel array column double/triple/etc.. consonant generation

Tags: php, arrays, excel

How would I auto generate an array (in PHP) for AA - ZZ and so on like AAA - ZZZ

```
$column_arr2= range("aa", "zz"); // NOT Working
$row_arr    = range(0,1000);
$column_arr = range("a", "z");

echo "Column2<pre>".print_r($column_arr2, true)."</pre><br />"; // prints a - z
echo "Row<pre>".print_r($row_arr, true)."</pre><br />";
echo "Column<pre>".print_r($column_arr, true)."</pre><br />";
```

Would like to make the number and alpha arrays dynamic as I'm using this for an excel document.

What I would like is:

```
$arr = ([0] => 'a', [1] => 'b', [2] => 'c', ...
        [26] => 'aa', [27] => 'ab', [28] => 'ac', ...
        [52] => 'ba', [53] => 'bb', [54] => 'bc', ...
       )
```

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[PHP supports incrementing strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
$array = array('A');
$current = 'A';
while ($current != 'ZZZ') {
    $array[] = ++$current;
}
```

Comment: +1 (since it works).  Man PHP has some weird behavior some times.  Useful behavior, but not behavior you'd expect...

Comment: Awesome!!! I had no idea PHP supported incrementing strings. One small not is you skip A but if you add it on array creation it works great

Comment: @ircmaxell - not so weird, because it's a feature inherited/stolen from Perl. What's weird is that you can't decrement strings using --$current;